# How to change color when hover over div id?

Tags: colors, background-color

I have made a div id in my html and draw the bars in my css.
Now i want to change the colors when hover over the bars.

here is a example of my html

```
<div id="balklongwaarde">
</div>
```

And here is my css where I draw the divs

```
#balklongwaarde{
height: 150px;
width: 40px;
border: 1px solid #2e9afe;
background: #2e9afe;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 200px;
margin-left: 200px;
}
```

How to change the background color when hover over the bars?

Answer (score 6):

in css

```
 #balklongwaarde:hover{background-color:red;}
```